# Recieving only last onclick event from foreach loop

Tags: javascript

I read about closures, but I could not apply to my code. The problem is I recieve only last onclick event from foreach loop.

Example:

I have 2 products, but onclick button event works only for second product, not for 1.

```
function load_products(products){
    products.forEach(function(product) {
        var msg="";
        msg+="<div id='quick_reply_"+product.product_id+"' class='message-from-client'>";
        msg+="<button type='button' id='quick_reply_button_"+product.product_id+"' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-quick-reply'>"+product.product_name+"</button>";
        msg+="<div class='mt10'></div>";
        getId('c-body').innerHTML+=msg;
        getId("quick_reply_button_"+product.product_id).onclick = function() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', chat.api+"?act=quick_reply", true);
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("chat_id", chatId);
            formData.append("type", product.product_id);
            xhr.send(formData);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: May you provide a working code snippet?

Comment: Are you trying to load the product and execute the onclick at the same time? If so - seems like your last call is overwriting the previous calls you make to the chat.api.

Comment: getId("quick_reply_button_"+product.product_id) could'nt work before the msg content is added to the DOM.
THe question is more, why why the last one do work.

Comment: @alpharomeo No, I trying to make clickable all buttons, not only last one.

Comment: @Jew Maybe you know how to do it another way? Maybe it will another function, I need a result

Answer (score 0):

The  beauty of javascript that you have many ways to do it.

Here is one way, by separating the function from the DOM at all.

Another way could be to add a wait, or using `new HTMLElement` so you can add events before adding it to the DOM.

```js
function load_products(products){
    products.forEach(function(product) {
        var msg="";
        msg+="<div id='quick_reply_"+product.product_id+"' class='message-from-client'>";
        msg+="<button type='button' onclick='do_post("+product.product_id+")' id='quick_reply_button_"+product.product_id+"' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-quick-reply'>"+product.product_name+"</button>";
        msg+="<div class='mt10'></div>";
        getId('c-body').innerHTML+=msg;
        //getId("quick_reply_button_"+product.product_id).onclick 
    });
}

do_post = function(product_id) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', chat.api+"?act=quick_reply", true);
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("chat_id", chatId);
            formData.append("type", product_id);
            xhr.send(formData);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by this line:

```
    getId('c-body').innerHTML+=msg;
```

This means that the already existing content is *replaced* by new HTML. This replacement means that any event handlers that were already bound to the existing content, are no longer bound to it.

Here are two solutions:

1. Split the loop into two loops: first do a loop to create the HTML content only, and then another loop to only bind the handlers.

   OR
2. Replace the above line by:

   ```
   getId('c-body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', msg);
   ```

   This will not touch the existing HTML, and so the previously attached handlers remain bound to the events.